# How can extras_require override

Tags: python-3.x

I want override `some-custom-lib` in `extras_require`

This is my setup.py summary

```py
VERSION = "1.0.0"

...

setup(
    name="my-lib",
    version="1.0.0",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(
        exclude=[
            "*.tests",
        ]
    ),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "attrs>=18.1.0,<=20.3.0",
        "structlog>=18.1.0,<22.0.0",
        f"some-custom-lib{VERSION}",
    ],
    extras_require={
        # For async
        "async": [
            f"some-custom-lib[async]{VERSION}",
        ]
    },
)
```

Now use in `poetry`

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "temp"
version = "0.1.0"

my-lib = {extras = ["async"],version = "~=1.0.0"}

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=1.1"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

But uninstalled `some-custom-lib`'s async libs
How can I solve It?